# LTR Elasticsearch creating feature to access text data as it is

Tags: elasticsearch

As per the documentation, the LTR feature set has to be defined using Mustache template. I am trying to create "feature1" to access a text value as one of the features to my LTR model and I am not sure if I am doing it right. Can anyone suggest me how to do it?

```
{
   "featureset": {
        "features": [
            {
                "name": "test_feature",
                "template_language": "mustache",
                "template": "{{#ctx.features.feature}} {{ctx.features.feature.value}} {{/ctx.features.feature}}"
                }
            ]
   }
}
```

This is giving me an error saying "Failed to derive xcontent"..